# ImageField needs Pillow to be installed

Tags: django

I made a model with `ImageField()`. But whenever I run `python manage.py` it says you need to install `pillow.ERRORS`:

```
sho.Product.image: (fields.E210) Cannot use ImageField because Pillow is not installed.
        HINT: Get Pillow at https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/ or run command "python -m pip
install Pillow".
```

Comment: so error is self explanatory ImageField requires Pillow library

Comment: whenever i open project i have to install pillow again and again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It did tell you how to fix it , You dont have the pillow library installed so the imagefield wont work unless you run `python -m pip install Pillow` . Running the command will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using old version of Django old version don't support for ImageField() without installing pillow. just update the Django package by running following command

```
you must do the following:
1- Update pip
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
2- If you already install Django update by using the following command
pip install --upgrade Django
or you can uninstall it using the following command
pip uninstall Django
3- If you don't install it yet use the following command
python -m pip install Django
4- Type your code

Enjoy
```

Answer (score -1):

Install Pillow library,  `pip install Pillow`

in your models.py import Pillow as below

```
from PIL import Image
```